# Chromatic aberration

Tags: python, performance, beginner, cython

`surface` is a `pygame.surface` object from the Pygame graphics library. It actually runs way faster than I thought it would for a first try. Still, have I made any obvious mistakes here? Is there any way to make it go even faster?

```
cdef mapped_chromatic_aberration(surface, numpy.ndarray[int,ndim=2] intensitymap):
    cdef int x,y,z,maxx,maxy,intensity
    cdef numpy.ndarray[unsigned char,ndim=3] array
    cdef numpy.ndarray[unsigned char,ndim=2] r,g,b
    r=pygame.surfarray.pixels_red(surface)
    g=pygame.surfarray.pixels_green(surface)
    b=pygame.surfarray.pixels_blue(surface)
    array=pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(surface)

    maxx,maxy=surface.get_rect().bottomright

    for x in range(maxx):
        for y in range(maxy):
            try:
                pass
                intensity=intensitymap[x,y]
                array[x,y,0]=r[x+intensity,y]
                array[x,y,1]=g[x,y+intensity]
                array[x,y,2]=b[x+intensity,y-intensity]
            except IndexError:
                pass

cdef random_chromatic_aberration(surface,int intensity=5):
    mapped_chromatic_aberration(surface,numpy.random.random_integers(-intensity,intensity,surface.get_rect().bottomright))
```

Answer (score 3):

At first glance, the double for loop seems to be very time consuming. Since you're using the numpy arrays, there is a way to get rid of it:

```
x = np.arange(array.shape[0])
y = np.arange(array.shape[1])
intensity = intensitymap.astype(int)
array[:, :, 0] = red[x + intensity, y]
array[:, :, 1] = green[x, y + intensity]
array[:, :, 2] = blue[x + intensity, y - intensity]
```

By the way, I would recommend you to use the [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/#example) JIT compiler. This will let you write pure python code. It is under active development now, and this is optimized for numpy arrays.